# Stylizing a table with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table, multiple-columns

I have created a table in which I will have an image of a person and information about them in the cell next to the image. My code is below

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td class="bg" colspan="2">JEFF DAVIS</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="24%">
            <img height="150" src="file:///C|/Users/Daniel/Desktop/photo1.jpg" width="150">
        </td>

        <td width="76%">
            <p>Name: Jeff Davis</p>

            <p>Favourite Color: Yellow</p>

            <p>Favourite Animal: My Cat</p>

            <p>Favourite Super Hero: Superman</p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Facebook Twitter Email</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the cell where I keep the information, or 'profile' of the person I want to have bullet points in two columns. Could somebody inform me of how to do this?
Also I would like the top cell, with the name in capitals to have rounded edges, I believe I can do this with CSS but I am a complete novice.

Comment: By using `ul` and `li` and wrapping them in a self clearing container and floating each of the `ul` to the `left`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle of your example using dots u mentioned.

```
<ul>   
     <li><p>Name: Jeff Davis</p></li>
     <li><p>Favourite Color: Yellow</p></li>
     <li><p>Favourite Animal: My Cat </p></li>
     <li><p>Favourite Super Hero: Superman</p></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kzgfu/

Is this want u ment?

P.s.: I dont quite understand what u mean with the capitals to have rounded edges. Could u show a picture of what u are meaning?

Rounded Cell from Danko http://jsfiddle.net/kzgfu/1/

And another rounded cell from me: http://jsfiddle.net/kzgfu/2/

Comment: Like this is border-raidus add this in your answer http://jsfiddle.net/kzgfu/1/ using class bg ... +1

Comment: Exactly.

I added another example of rounded edges here: http://jsfiddle.net/kzgfu/2/

Comment: I liked the way you answered and also asked the doubt rather than posting only doubt in your answer, as new users tend to do that... so +1 from me as well

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what he means by rounded corners, not sure though

```
table td:nth-child(1){
background-color:#333;
color:#fff;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ldbu4/1/

```
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="bg">JEFF DAVIS</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="24%"><img src="file:///C|/Users/Daniel/Desktop/photo1.jpg" width="150" height="150" /></td>
    <td width="76%"><p>Name: Jeff Davis</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Favourite Color: Yellow</li>
            <li>Favourite Animal: My Cat </li>
            <li>Favourite Super Hero: Superman</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">Facebook Twitter Email</td>
</tr>
```

and css

```
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

 td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td
{
    padding: 10px;
}

th
{
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go

[JsFiddle Bullet points and round corners around capitals](http://jsfiddle.net/lahmf/fGvNx/5/)

CSS:

```
.bg {
text-align:center;
background:green;
border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;}
```

HTML:

```
 <li> <p>Favourite Color: Yellow</p>          </li>
 <li> <p>Favourite Animal: My Cat </p>        </li>
 <li> <p>Favourite Super Hero: Superman</p>   </li>
 <li> <p>  Facebook Twitter Email</p>         </li>   </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle example using divs (I know it's not what you asked, but just so you have different options) and two columns for the bullet points.

[http://jsfiddle.net/jprZ7](http://jsfiddle.net/jprZ7/)

```
<div style="width:50%;">
    <div style="width:100%; text-align:center; border-radius: 15px; background-color:#CCC;">
        JEFF DAVIS
    </div>
    <div style="width:24%; float:left;">
        <img src="file:///C|/Users/Daniel/Desktop/photo1.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
    </div>
    <div style="width:76%; float:left;">
        <ul style="float:left;">
            <li>
                <p>Name: Jeff Davis</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Favourite Color: Yellow</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul style="float:left;">
                <li>
                <p>Favourite Animal: My Cat</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Favourite Super Hero: Superman</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```